# Generic in function doesn't check argument type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm expecting that typescript will throw an error because I'm passing the wrong number of elements in `EntryPoints`, but it doesn't happen.

```js
function createContext<T>(defaultValue: T): T[] {
  return [defaultValue]
}

interface EntryPoints {
  parentSelector: string;
}
interface SomeType {
  entryPoints: EntryPoints[];
}
const defaultData = {
  entryPoints: [{
    parentSelector: '',
    foo: 1 // <-- expecting error here
  }]
}
createContext<SomeType>(defaultData)
```

Same code without generic works as expected

```js
function createContext<T>(defaultValue: T): T[] {
  return [defaultValue]
}

interface EntryPoints {
  parentSelector: string;
}
interface SomeType {
  entryPoints: EntryPoints[];
}
const defaultData: SomeType = {
  entryPoints: [{
    parentSelector: '',
    foo: 1 // <-- throwing error here
  }]
}
createContext(defaultData)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQYQdgDygB4AVAPgAoATNYDEAGygDUNGQ0AuRUgSh6kA2gF1EAbwBQiROiggUSIbXpNW7TiMkBfSZJhhsKehDSIAooZQBPAApwDUAM4TpiAA4Z0hgMppGaNBwKDxOUCgGAOYA3Dr6hmjGGKaIPnAAtmik1u5mUjJoVnYOhk48luHFjk6isboQCGGIKgzMACJYGIgAvK4FRfbVPEL5MojAcHA8AIwANG4ynt5QfgFBIYgA5JvzMtpa9ehYuPhoRMRpmdm5VC1qHVAYfHp6DWBNd+2dAEw8l1k5My9UaFSqDUrDUYyCZTRBzBYeLyg1aBKDBHjbXaIfZxSSoTDYPAJIg0OitKAPDDfPhAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an [object freshness issue](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/freshness.html) so the *additional* key is allowed.

If you explicitly pass the object it will be properly typed checked:

```js
function createContext<T>(defaultValue: T): T[] {
  return [defaultValue];
}

interface EntryPoints {
  parentSelector: string;
}

interface SomeType {
  entryPoints: EntryPoints[];
}

createContext<SomeType>({
  entryPoints: [
    {
      parentSelector: "",
      foo: 1 // <-- errors as expected here
    }
  ]
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQYQdgDygB4AVAPgAoATNYDEAGygDUNGQ0AuRUgSh6kA2gF1EAbwCwAKESJ0UECiRDa9Jq3acRAbhkBfGTJhhsKehDSIAoqZQBPAApwTUAM4SZcgA4Z0pgGU0RjRoOBQeNygUEwBzPWlDaWNTNHMMS0QAuABbNFJ7byspWUQ0OycXUzceW2jK1zdRBKSZVExsPFSiYmy8gqKqErly+udGniEvOU9SmcRffyggkLCIxAAiDYAaafngODgeAEZEAHozxGIAWmuygiLoOLKUFHDEAAs0tD3EJLkRAY+AkgA)

Comment: This isn't type widening. Type widening is a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is the difference between

1. type checking at the point of assigning a **literal** to a type and
2. type checking at the point of assigning a **variable** to a type.

Consider that we have two types. One of them has one more property than the other has.

```
type Foo = {
  foo: string;
};

type FooBar = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};
```

When assigning an **object literal** to a type, **additional properties are NOT allowed**.

```
// Object literal may only specify known properties,
// and 'bar' does not exist in type 'Foo'.
const foo: Foo = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar" // <---- bar is not allowed on Foo.
};
```

When assigning a **variable** to a type, **additional properties are allowed**.

```
const fooBar: FooBar = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar" // <---- bar is going to be allowed on Foo
};

const foo: Foo = fooBar; // <---- see, no error
```

It is okay to assign `fooBar` to `foo` because `fooBar` is a variable not an object literal and can therefore include unknown properties.